# Can't understand syntax of params

Tags: reactjs

I cant understand params syntax. What does ({todo, destroyTodo}) actually mean in this case? Why can’t we just use "props" as param?

```
 const TodoItem = ({todo, destroyTodo}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {todo.text}
      <span onClick={destroyTodo}> x </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have shown creates a new component using a javascript function. The `{todo,destroyTodo}` is a json object which is passed as `props` to the component and destructured into 2 variables called todo and destroyTodo.
It is a shorthand for

```
const TodoItem = (props) => {
  const  {todo, destroyTodo} = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {todo.text}
      <span onClick={destroyTodo}> x </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The same component created as a class would be

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component{

render(){
   return (
    <div>
      {this.props.todo.text}
      <span onClick={this.props.destroyTodo}> x </span>
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually pass your props object but in the case when you're doing `<TodoItem {...props}/>` you pass all props from a parent and need to point it like

```
const TodoItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.todo.text}
      <span onClick={props.destroyTodo}> x </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```